# Stop Observing Events with JS Prototype not working with .bind(this)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm working on a Javascript class based on the Prototype library. This class needs to observe an event to perform a drag operation (the current drag-drop controls aren't right for this situation), but I'm having problems making it stop observing the events.

Here's a sample that causes this problem:

```
var TestClass = Class.create({
    initialize: function(element) {
        this.element = element;
        Event.observe(element, 'mousedown', function() {
            Event.observe(window, 'mousemove', this.updateDrag.bind(this));
            Event.observe(window, 'mouseup', this.stopDrag.bind(this));
        });
    },
    updateDrag: function(event) {
        var x = Event.pointerX(event);
        var y = Event.pointerY(event);
        this.element.style.top = y + 'px';
        this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
    },
    stopDrag: function(event) {
        console.log("stopping drag");
        Event.stopObserving(window, 'mousemove', this.updateDrag.bind(this));
        Event.stopObserving(window, 'mouseup', this.stopDrag.bind(this));
    }
});
```

Without .bind(this) then this.element is undefined, but with it the events don't stop being observed (the console output does occur though).

Comment: Glad that helped. I just updated my answer because I noticed an (unrelated) bug in `initialize`, may be worth taking a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bind`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/function/prototype/bind/) returns a new function reference every time you call it (that's its job :-) ), and [`stopObserving`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/event/stopobserving/) will only unhook the handler if the function reference is an `===` match.

To fix this, remember the event handler you bound as a property and then use that property with `stopObserving`. Or, if you're in charge of that element, you can unhook *all* handlers for the `mousemove` and `mouseup` events by simply leaving off the third parameter. (See the linked docs for more about leaving off parameters to `stopObserving`).

So either:

```
initialize: function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.boundUpdateDrag = this.updateDrag.bind(this);
    this.boundStopDrag = this.stopDrag.bind(this);
    Event.observe(element, 'mousedown', function() {
        // Off-topic, but see note at end of answer, unrelated bug here
        Event.observe(window, 'mousemove', this.boundUpdateDrag);
        Event.observe(window, 'mouseup', this.boundStopDrag);
    });
},
stopDrag: function(event) {
    console.log("stopping drag");
    Event.stopObserving(window, 'mousemove', this.boundUpdateDrag);
    Event.stopObserving(window, 'mouseup', this.boundStopDrag);
}
```

Or just

```
stopDrag: function(event) {
    console.log("stopping drag");
    Event.stopObserving(window, 'mousemove');
    Event.stopObserving(window, 'mouseup');
}
```

But note that the latter removes *all* handlers for those events on that element (well, the ones hooked up via Prototype).

---

Off-topic, but note that there's a bug in your `initialize` function: It's using `this` in the handler for `mousedown`, but not ensuring that `this` is set to what it should be set to. You'll need to bind that anonymous function, or use a variable in `initialize` to take advantage of the fact that that anonymous function is a closure.

So either use bind again:

```
initialize: function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.boundUpdateDrag = this.updateDrag.bind(this);
    this.boundStopDrag = this.stopDrag.bind(this);
    Event.observe(element, 'mousedown', (function() {
        Event.observe(window, 'mousemove', this.boundUpdateDrag);
        Event.observe(window, 'mouseup', this.boundStopDrag);
    }).bind(this));
},
```

Or use the fact you're defining a closure anyway:

```
initialize: function(element) {
    var self;

    self = this; // Remember 'this' on a variable that will be in scope for the closure
    this.element = element;
    this.boundUpdateDrag = this.updateDrag.bind(this);
    this.boundStopDrag = this.stopDrag.bind(this);
    Event.observe(element, 'mousedown', function() {
        // Note we're using 'self' rather than 'this'
        Event.observe(window, 'mousemove', self.boundUpdateDrag);
        Event.observe(window, 'mouseup', self.boundStopDrag);
    });
},
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I should have read the docs more closely. Unhooking all the handlers works perfectly.