# Prototype | keyup Event.stopObserving() not working when handler is bound to class

Tags: class, prototypejs, bind, observer-pattern

Here's my beef: I'm observing the document for a keyup and then calling a handler. The handler is calling a function of a class and is bound to the class's context. When the function is called and my conditionals are met, it's supposed to stop observing the handler. But its not.

Created a class, this is the function I'm calling on page:

```
look_for: function(key_combo) {

    this.keys_array = key_combo.split("+");

    this.match_key_handler = this.match_keys.bind(this);

    document.observe('keyup', this.match_key_handler);

},
```

This calls the document to observe keyup and calls this.match_keys(). As you can see, it's assigned to a handler because the function needs to be bound. Below is the match_keys functions:

```
match_keys: function() {

  // matching the keys here, blah blah

  if(this.keys_matched) {

    document.stopObserving('keyup',this.match_key_handler);

   }

}
```

However, when the conditional is met, it doesn't stop observing! If I stopObserving all keyups on the document, it will unregister this function  but I want it to only unregister the match_key_handler.

StackOverflow, help me out! Below is another post thats similar. Followed what was on the page but still no dice.

[Stop Observing Events with JS Prototype not working with .bind(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567759/stop-observing-events-with-js-prototype-not-working-with-bindthis)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted... some questions: is `look_for` always called before `match_keys`? Is `look_for` called multiple times (sets a new handler each time but only keeps track of one)?

Comment: Kit, I fixed my solution by doing reworking some of the code. However, I think figured out what I was doing wrong. 

When calling look_for, it was being called in a anonymous function like this:

document.observe('keyup',function() {
   myclass.look_for(key_combo);
});

Even though I registered my handler correctly, I couldn't ever reach it because I was calling another function that was calling match_keys.

Derped!